# how to convert bigendian squashfs file system to little endian

Tags: linux, conversion, squashfs

Are there any tools to convert big endian squashfs file system to little endian?

Comment: I suspect the answer is going to be "extract the files from your squashfs image and then generate a new one with appropriate endianness".

Comment: suppose we have a squashfs file system (test.bin) in big endian format, i have to convert that to little endian format, (mksquashfs tool does not support that feature)

Comment: I didn't know squashfs has an endianness. Are you experiencing an error?  What leads you to want to change it?

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can do it with `jffs2dump`. it's probably preinstalled in your linux, if not you can find it here: https://github.com/project-magpie/jffs2dump

Comment: not about jffs2, but squashfs. Unlike JFFS2, I'd be surprised if squashfs actually cares about endianness at all.